# How can set the ie9 standards for all the pages in the site

Tags: html, tags, internet-explorer-9, standards, meta

I have try this more then 2 hours.My site have html5 and css.In IE 8,9,10 some of my side page display document mode as Quirks so the page is not looking good.I have checked in Google they show add the meta tag after the title,but the page still display in quirks mode.how can change the page default type as ie9 standards.The below code i used for standard tag conversion.

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=10; IE=9; IE=8;" />
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=100" />
```

Comment: are you using all of them?

Comment: no only one for each time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a valid `DOCTYPE` set on every page? If not, IE automatically goes into quirks mode on pages that have no `DOCTYPE`.

Comment: How can set the document type.

Comment: On every page, at the very top have: `<!DOCTYPE html>`